# GC Overhead Limit Exceeded when filling Hashmap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hashmap

When my java program starts, it fills a hashmap with thousands of objects. The key is a string and the value is a set of objects.

The program is running at full tilt and throws a Out of Memory Exception: GC Overhead Limit Exceeded when it reaches around 10000 keys.

I have read that it could be that the underlying array has to constantly resize. But id like to be able to solve this without simply increasing the heap size.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `HashMap`'s `initialCapacity` constructor to set it to desired size, if you know how many keys you'll have upfront.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't but it will definitely be more than the default of 16. Anywhere between a few thousand and a few million.

Comment: can you try TreeMap instead, out of curiosity. That may help you understand if the nature of the problem in Map implementation. Keys must implement ordering on comparator provided.

Answer (score 2):

You need to model the size of your data, plus the per-element overhead of `HashMap`, in order to determine your heap requirements.

For the sake of simplicity I'll assume you're running a 64-bit JVM using compressed OOPS (OOP = ordinary object pointer). This gives a 12-byte header per object, and a 4-byte object reference. I'll further assume you're using a `HashMap` with a default load factor of 0.75.

With 10,000 elements, the table size is a minimum of 10,000 / 0.75 = 13,333. However, the table size is always a power of two, so it'll probably be 16,384 long. That gives 65,536 bytes -- 64KB.

Each element stored in a `HashMap` also requires the creation of an internal `Node` object, which has four 4-byte fields (hash, key, value, next) plus 12 bytes for the object header, giving 28 bytes per `Node` object. With 10,000 elements, that's 280KB.

The `HashMap` table size plus the internal `Node` objects thus require 344KB of overhead for storing 10,000 key-value pairs. That's not causing you to run out of memory. Changing the initial capacity of the `HashMap` will reduce the copying overhead from resizing, but the amount of temporary extra memory it takes is negligible compared to a typical heap size of hundreds of MB or several GB.

If your heap size is 1 GB and you're running out of memory at 10,000 map entries, then each key-value pair takes about 100KB. You won't be able to load a few million keys unless you drastically increase your heap size, or you reduce the size of each key-value pair, or some combination of both.

Comment: Stuart, thank you for a detailed answer. Is running out of memory virtually synonymous with the garbage collector working too hard? Presumably it is working so hard because it is desperately trying to reclaim memory

Comment: @JohnSmith Not synonymous, but one of the symptoms of running out of memory is when the garbage collector runs too often. Suppose you have a program that allocates lots of small objects, and 90% of them are garbage. It's pretty easy to see that the heap will asymptotically approach being 100% full but it'll take a really long time to get there. The symptom is that GC will run more and more frequently and eventually consume more CPU than application threads. That's approximately when the JVM will throw the "GC overhead limit exceeded" OOME that you saw.

Answer (score 1):

You are geting Out of Memory because internal array is doubled each time when a certain threshold is met. So you need to make sure it won't be happening. If you know the number of objects you need to store in the map just use constructor `HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)` and provide the expected size in the first parameter. If you don't know the number of objects you still can try to set `initialCapacity` so some approximate value and/or play with `loadFactor` parameter (default value is 0.75) - the larger the value the larger the threshold at wich there will be the resize.

Answer (score 0):

You should use profilers and memory analyzer tools for performance and memory related issues.
One of the tips I would do is to configure JVM with flag 
JAVA_OPTS=-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
Then when you've got this exception and JVM crashes, you may take this dump and use MAT memory analyzer tool to analyze objects distribution and root paths.
Also one would prefer to use Java Mission Control JMC distributed with Java and it's flight recorder. Please note that flight recorder is available since Java 7 update 40

Comment: Why wasting time if the reason is already clear for the author?

Comment: A heap dump is a fine approach to analyzing out-of-memory errors. The OP thinks that `HashMap` table resizing is the culprit, but that's extremely unlikely.

Comment: Reason is not clear neither for the author nor for us, this is his assumption, and our goal is to find the truth.